# Use custom id "foreign key name" for use it like object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Title isn't explicit, but I didn't know how to explain my problem in few words.

I've a **Sale model** with this fields:

```
create_table "sales", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    ...
    t.integer  "seller_id"
    t.integer  "buyer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    ...
  end
```

In a view, I'm able to do that with **Category**:

```
<td><%= link_to sale.category.label, category_path(sale.category) %></td>
```

Cause I think Rails convention know category_id is related to an Category object

So, I want to do exactly the same for seller_id and buyer_id which are both User.
Unfortunally, I fall on error when I try:

```
<td><%= sale.seller.first_name %></td>
```

output:
undefined method `seller' for Sale

There, how my Models are linked:

**User:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers
    has_many :sales

end
```

**Sale:**

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "seller_id"
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "buyer_id"
```

EDIT:

Yeah, it's make more sense. I had misunderstood the documentation about that.

But I've still an error:
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

I think it's cause Rails didn't find the User... But I've a good value in seller_id...

EDIT 2:

Still not working with:

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers
    has_many :sales, foreign_key: :seller_id
    has_many :sales, foreign_key: :buyer_id
end
```

**Sale model:**

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: :User
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: :User
end
```

Same error on :

```
<td><%= sale.seller.first_name %></td>
```

**output**

undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tweak your `associations` in your `Sale` model.

This should work

```
Class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User",foreign_key: "seller_id", 
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User",foreign_key: "buyer_id"
end
```

Comment: ack got beaten to it, but yes, tweaking the associations should allow you to do what you intend.
The reason it works for the customer is because of the relation, since it expects a Customer to be passed along in the URL helper.

Comment: foreign key in this case isn't required/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the models should seem as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sales, foreign_key: :seller_id
   has_many :buys, foreign_key: :buyer_id
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :seller, class_name: :User 
   belongs_to :buyer, class_name: :User
end
```

So when you use `belongs_to` you should just specify `class_name`, but in class that contains `has_many` related to the specific `belongs_to` you should explicitly denote the name of field in the `belongs_to` class.